# Vue How to set data-attribute to the body with current route name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm thinking about to add some data-attribute to the body of my `vue`-app, where the attribute value should be the current route's name. I don't want to use the [vue-body-class](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-body-class) package but keep it super simple.

So, right now I do this in each of my main components, let's say the `About.vue`:

```
mounted() {
  document.body.setAttribute("data-route", this.$route.name);
},

destroyed() {
  document.body.removeAttribute("data-route", this.$route.name);
}
```

this works ok, but I was thinking if there maybe is a better way to do this? Maybe in the `router.js`?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: maybe something [in this documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) will help

Answer (score 0):

the `vue` way would be to use `refs` to grab elements not directly from the document object. See here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs